# Prove $S^1\times I\to D^2,(s,t)\mapsto ts$ is an identification.

Tags: general-topology

First of all, every map here is continuous. I'm trying to prove the following:

If every $S^1\to X$ is homotopic to a constant map $S^1\to X$ then every map $S^1\to X$ extends to a map $D^2\to X$

Let's say $f:S^1\to X$ is given and there is an homotopy $\{f_t\}_{t\in I}$ with $f_0$ a constant map and $f_1=f$. Define $F:S^1\times I\to X$ by $F(s,t)=f_t(s)$. Consider now the map $p:S^1\times I:\to D^2,p(s,t)=ts$ ($ts$ is scalar multiplication). If $p$ is an identification then $Fp^{-1}:D^2\to X$ is defined because $f_0$ is a constant map, continuous because $p$ is an identification and extends the given $f$ because $f_1=f$.

So it remains to show that $p$ is indeed an identification (I actually think it's an open map and this might have something to do with the fact that $\cdot:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an open map, I'm not sure though.)

Answer (score 1):

If the word "identification" means a bijection, then your solution is incorrect.  Note that $p(\_,0)=0$ is constant, whence $p$ is not a bijection.

I think you meant $F:\mathbb{S}^1\times I\to X$.  I suggest the following.  Note that $F(\_,0)$ is constant.  Hence, by the universal property of the quotient spaces, we see that $F$ factors through $\left(\mathbb{S}^1\times I\right)/\sim$, where $(s,0)\sim (r,0)$ for all $s,r\in \mathbb{S}^1$.  That is, for a unique continuous map $\tilde{F}:\left(\mathbb{S}^1\times I\right)/\sim \to X$, we have $F=\tilde{F}\circ \kappa$, where $\kappa:\left(\mathbb{S}^1\times I\right)\to \left(\mathbb{S}^1\times I\right)/\sim$ is the quotient map.  Show that $\left(\mathbb{S}^1\times I\right)/\sim$ is indeed the closed disc $\mathbb{D}^2$.

---

**EDIT**: After clarification on an unfamiliar term by the OP.

If $p:\mathbb{S}^1\times I \to \mathbb{D}^2$ is a surjective closed continuous map, then it is a quotient map.  (In fact, $p=\kappa$ in my definition, under the identification $\left(\mathbb{S}^1\times I\right)/\sim$ with $\mathbb{D}^2$, i.e., $\big[(s,t)\big]=st$ and $\big[(s,0)\big]=0$ for all $s\in\mathbb{S}^1$ and $t\in(0,1]$.)  However, $p$ is the restriction of the multiplication $\cdot:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which is a closed map, onto a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.  Hence, $p$ is a closed map.  That is, $p$ is indeed a quotient map.  Then, the rest is trivial, and note that the map $\tilde{F}$ given above is the same as the OP's $Fp^{-1}$.

Comment: By identification I mean a surjection $p:X\to Y$ such that $U$ is open in $Y$ iff $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, not a bijection.

Comment: Then, how do you define $p^{-1}$, if $p$ is not a bijection?

Comment: $p^{-1}$ is the inverse image of $U$, i.e. $p^{-1}(U)=\{x\in X:p(x)\in U\}$.

Comment: Then, why do you say $F\circ p^{-1}:\mathbb{D}^2\to X$ is defined?   What is $p^{-1}$ here?

Comment: $Fp^{-1}(p(x))=F(x)$, i.e. one has to prove that $p(x)=p(x')\implies F(x)=F(x')$, so that $Fp^{-1}$ is indeed well defined.

Comment: Why do you expect that $Fp^{-1}$ defined this way is a continuous map?  (It is, but why?)

Comment: Check Dugundji's book pages 123 and 124: Transgression theorem about  identifications, this is the very same situation.

Comment: I'm not checking it.  I know it is continuous, and I know why.  I'm asking you if you really know.  Assume you that you know why then I'm really curious now how you can't prove that $p$ is an open surjection since this is a much more trivial part than the continuity of your $Fp^{-1}$.

Comment: It's not that I can't prove that $p$ is a surjection, that's trivial, I can't prove $p$ is an identification (I actually suspect it's an open map (this implies identification), but I'm not sure). If you know why it's an open map, please elaborate on that.

Comment: I retract my statement that $p$ being open is trivial.  It is wrong.  Consider a neighborhood $V$ within a small $\epsilon>0$ of $1$ in $\mathbb{S}^1$.  Then $V\times I$ is open in $\mathbb{S}^1\times I$.  However, $p(V\times I)$ is an open sector of the unit disc union the origin, which is not open in $\mathbb{D}^2$.

Comment: However, have you considered proving that $p$ is a closed map?  It is true in this case.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. It's true that $p$ is not an open map as your example shows, but the reason $p$ is closed is not because multiplication $\cdot:R\times R\to R$ is a closed map (consider the set $\{(n,1/n^2):n\in N\}$ whose image is $\{1/n:n\in N\}$ that is not closed in $R$) but  because $S^1\times I$ is compact and $D^2$ is hausdorff. What do you think?